# Can an eigenvalue equation have no solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

For an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$, can the eigenvalue equation
$$\Omega|v\rangle=w|v\rangle$$
where $\Omega$ is a linear operator, have no solution besides from the trivial solutiom $|v\rangle=|0\rangle?$

When reading about how to find eigenvalues/eigenvectors, it was always assumed that $\Omega|v\rangle=w|v\rangle$ has a nontrivial solution and hence we can use the charateristic equation $\det(\Omega-wI)$ to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot. To be more precise: if $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $\Omega$, then there are are always non-zero solutions of the equation $\Omega v=\lambda v$. That's so because $\det(\Omega-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0$ if and only if the kernel of $\Omega-\lambda\operatorname{Id}$ is not reduced to $\{0\}$.

Comment: +1, note that there may be no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}$, for example, though

Comment: What I mean is if the eigenvalue equation has no solution, we won't even reach the characteristic equation. To reach the characteristic equation, we need to first assume that the eigenvalue equation has a solution, right?

Comment: The characteristic equation is the equation $\det(\Omega-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0$. What do you mean when you say that we don't reach it? What prevents us from reaching it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your operator is a finite-dimensional real or complex matrix, then it will always have eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C}$. Note that a real finite-dimensional matrix may not have real eigenvalues and, as a result, it may be not diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R}$.

The domain of the operator may add restrictions on the spectrum. This happens, for instance, when studying operators acting on symmetric matrices. The fact that the domain is not the set of all matrices but those which are symmetric changes the spectrum.

This is different in the infinite dimensional setting. For instance, consider the shift operator $S$ acting on infinite bounded sequences as

$$S(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0, x_1, x_2,\ldots).$$

This operator has no eigenvalues. Indeed, for such a value to exists we would need to find $\lambda$ such that $Sx=\lambda x$, $x\ne 0$, which is equivalent to saying that

$$0=\lambda x_1,\ x_1=\lambda x_2, x_2=\lambda x_3,\ldots$$

It is clear that there is no such $\lambda$. So, this operator has no eigenvalues.

In general the spectrum operators acting on infinite-dimensional vector spaces is more complicated than in the finite-dimensional case. The domain of the operator has also dramatic impact on the spectrum. This can be observed by looking at the spectrum of operators arising in the analysis of PDEs.